# Swarm Intelligence - what kinds of problems are effectively solved?

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for **practical problem (or implementations, applications) examples** which are effectively algoritmized using **swarm intelligence**. I found that multicriteria optimization is one example. Are there any others?

IMHO swarm-intelligence should be added to the tags

Comment: Here's your tag. Anything helpful you'd like to contribute to the tag's wiki?

Comment: Thanks I still do research about computational intelligence and swarms, I am not an expert now ;)

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for toy problems or more for real-world applications?

In the latter category I know variants on swarm intelligence algorithms are used in Hollywood for CGI animations such as large (animated) armies riding the fields of battle.

Related but more towards the toy-problem end of the spectrum you can model large crowds with similar algorithms, and use it for example to simulate disaster-scenarios. AFAIK the Dutch institute TNO has research groups on this topic, though I couldn't find an English link just by googling.

One suggestion for a place to start further investigation would be this PDF book:

http://www.cs.vu.nl/~schut/dbldot/collectivae/sci/sci.pdf

That book also has an appendix (B) with some sample projects you could try and work on.

If you want to get a head start there are several frameworks (scientific use) for multi-agent systems such as swarming intelligence (most of 'em are written with Java I think). Some of them include sample apps too. For example have a look at these:

Repast:
http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_3/

Swarm.org:
http://swarm.org/

Netlogo:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo

*Post edited, added more info.*

Comment: I am looking for real word applications and theretical problems where swarm intelligence "should be" used

Could you provide more information about CGI animations and disaster-scenarios simulations?

Comment: I edited my original answer with more information (mostly consisting of links). Good luck with your investigation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will take your question like: what kind of real-world problems SI can solve?

There are alot. Swarm intelligence is based on the complex behaviour of swarms, where agents in the swarm coordinate and cooperate by executing very simple rules to generate an emergent complex auto organized behaviour. Also, the agents often make a deliberation process to make efficient decisions, and also, the emergent behaviour of the swarms allows them to find patterns, learn and adapt to their environment.  Therefore, real-world applications based on SI are those that often required coordination and cooperation techniques, optimization process, exploratory analysis, dynamical poblems, etc. Some of these are:

1. Optimization techniques (mathematical functions for example)
2. Coordination of a swarm of robots (to organize inventory for example)
3. Routing in communication networks. (This is also dynamical combinatorial optimization)
4. Data analysis (usually exploratory, like clustering). SI has alot of applications in data mining and machine learning. This allows SI algorithms to find interesting patterns in big sets of data.
5. Np problems in general

I'm sure there are alot more. You should check the book:

"Swarm Intelligence: from natural to artificial systems". This is the basic book.

Take care.